# how to set each layout below another layout inside relative layout in android

Tags: android

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearalyout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#0070c0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/acceptbutton"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/accept_icon" />


            <View

                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cfcfcf" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cplacereached"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/map_icon"/>



            <View

                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cfcfcf" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dataentry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/dataentry_icon"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fraghome_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearalyout1">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fraghome_map"
            android:text="151121321"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Xml i want to display 4 layout inside relative-layout There are 4 view Listview ,Linarlayout, relativelayout and then Textview i want to display out of 10 i want to display listview 2 part, then linarlayout 1 part horizontally and then relative layout 6 part and then last textview 1 part each vertically but its unable to display while ihave appliead each item below please look my code where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Do you have a sketch of how you want your views to look like?

Comment: yes wait am giving you

Comment: http://snag.gy/u4n7t.jpg

Comment: Also please note that making ListView `wrap_content` won't have any effect. You must specify a height in dp or it will take the entire height of its parent container

Comment: in your code every thing is fine but just remove android:layout_alignParentTop="true" in your text view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a specific height for your list view. You should avoid setting wrap_content on a list view and there are plenty of online resources out there mentioning why. Here is a modified version of your layout xml that outputs the result you expect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearalyout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/acceptbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="#2a7fff" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cfcfcf" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cplacereached"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"
            android:background="#fa3a3a" />


        <View

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cfcfcf" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dataentry"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="#7dea58" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fraghome_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_distance_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearalyout1"
        android:background="#f594df">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="You Map Fragment Here" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Bottom Text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]